# Trigger another function until it finishes first one

Tags: python, multithreading

I searched so many solutions in `stackoverflow`,`google` and i found nothing solution to my problem.I knew there are many questions like this but i didn't found any solution from that questions.

**My Problem is:**

I am writing a script in python which will call two different functions by using `threading` module.I need to call second function until first function is finished because i am downloading the data in first function and i have to use the same data in second function.I am storing the data in the form of list in a file.

**My script for calling functions:**

```
def trigger_fiftyusers():
    try:
        for k in range(50):

            # calling first function
            syncUpFun = threading.Thread(target=func1)
            syncUpFun.start()
            syncUpFun.join()

            # calling second function
            syncDownFun = threading.Thread(target=func2)
            syncDownFun.start()
            syncDownFun.join()
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

**for example:**

my first function is like:

```
def func1():
    list1=[]
    print "func1"
    # some code here
    list1.append("some data")
    return list1
```

my second function is like:

```
def func2():
    print "func2"
    # some code here for getting the data from func1
    return list1
```

**and output should be:**

```
func1
func1
func1
func1

func2
func2
func2
func2
```

i am using Python 2.7.12 in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Why not iterating twice? First time calling 50 times for func1 and join them all, then [when ready], Iterate again for func2

Comment: You can start another thread in func1, so when it finished it will start thread2

Comment: Why you want to run 2 threads ? Func2 has to wait until func1 is finished - so simply decorate func1 with func2 to process the result ?

Comment: operation of func1 and func2 is different

Comment: @Aviad i dont' want to iterate two times. why should i waste my time to iterate two times while i have chance of completing in one..??

Comment: @shiva So you can create a nested method that wraps both calls, than calling the method in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

I modified `func1`, try with this changes, I think it will execute the same way you are thinking.

```
def func1():
 list1=[]
 print "func1"
 # some code here
 list1.append("some data")
 syncDownFun = threading.Thread(target=func2)
 syncDownFun.start()
 syncDownFun.join()
 return list1
```

Comment: @ Sanjay is it possible if trigger_fiftyusers() and func1(),func2() in different scrips..??

Comment: yes its possible finc1, func2 in different scripts, you just need to import and call them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap func1 and func2 call, somthine like:

```
def trigger_fiftyusers():

    def _wrapper():
        func1()
        func2()

    #Send them all
    threads = []
    for k in range(50):
        t = threading.Thread(target=_wrapper)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    #Wait for all of them
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```